# PHP Return Array in JSON , what happen this return include index? How To Fix?

Tags: php, oop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ep0e.png)

```
$table = $this->Execute("select * from data ");

        $result = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table))
        {
         array_push($result, $row);
        }
        return $result;
```

this my code, 
i dont know why my result including the index

Answer (score 1):

Its because of this statement:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table))`

You are getting numeric indexes as well as text keys.

Replace this by:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)) // will return only associate (string) keys.`

OR

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) // will return only associate (string) keys.`

This will not include numeric indexes.

References:

[mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

[mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  its  worked for me, Thx a lot Pupil,   i have work hard and realy confused me, because ths first time i have this problem, thx

Comment: @IkhbalFuady, you are welcome.